# Rendering views without master page in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, renderaction

I have a few views on my website that i need to include on a start page. However, just using Html.Renderaction renders the master page and the whole shebang.

How would i go about just rendering the content?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few ways.

Make sure your returning PartialView from your Controller.

`return PartialView("MyView");`

Or you can set Layout to String.Empty or null inside the view.

```
@{
Layout=String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: How would i set the layout to null with classic asp? I can't use razor for arbitrary reasons

Comment: Place the views in an ascx file or in an aspx file without a masterpage