# One view ignoring master layout

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rendering views without master page in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134744/rendering-views-without-master-page-in-mvc3)

I have one view in my project (a bill) and I would like this view to not be shown in a master view wrapper - rather I just want the HTML within the view to be shown. What is the correct way to make a view ignore loading a master layout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the correct way to make a view ignore loading a master layout?

You could put the following at the top of your view:

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
```

Or from within the controller action that is supposed to serve this view return a `PartialView` instead of a `View`:

```
public ActionResuilt SomeAction()
{
    return PartialView("_SomePartialView");
}
```

Or even return a view and specify a null Layout:

```
public ActionResuilt SomeAction()
{
    return View("SomeView", null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so returning a partial view will return always without the master layout?

Comment: Yeah, returning a `PartialView` will not render the Layout.

Comment: Thanks will accept when I can